# How to split/make tables narrower for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table

I'm trying to get the tables on this website to behave properly on mobile devices:
http://whitehallrow.com/classic-whitehall-spirit-17-slide-seat-model/

There are two tables on the page; the specifications table and the boat options pricing table. I want the specs table to split in the middle and wrap, so that all the bold words are on the left of the screen and the data is on the right.

I also want the pricing table to become narrower so that it doesn't run off the side of the page. I've tried assigning each column a width in percentage, but I can't seem to get any results from that.

I'm not great at dealing with HTML tables, so I'm a little lost here. How can I make them cooperate?

Comment: Your "specifications" table isn't really expressing tabular data, its being used here purely for layout purposes (beam and power have what to do with each other?).

Comment: Yes, the table is mainly just so that the data can be read easily. Each row expresses two unrelated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, we can't teach you HTML here. You will need to learn that yourself.

Second, the page is IMHO far too overengineered. Are you using some content management system with a ready made theme? Because the HTML and CSS are far too "heavy weight" for such a simple site. That will make changes more difficult, especially for mobile "optimization".

For the specs table: Simply use one two-column table with eight rows instead of a four by four table.

However if you want to keep the same/similar layout for desktop browsers, it would be bit more complicated.

For the price table: Remove both the hard-coded `style="width: 400px` and the `width: 100%` from the style sheet. (The latter will affect all tables, but having `width: 100%` on all tables isn't a good idea to begin with). That way the tables will re-size automatically based on content and screen width. You'll just need add some padding to the table cells, so that the values aren't squashed up to each other.